# Cannot convert this series to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this pandas dataframe df:

```
Exchange    Dir  Price      Total
BTCAlpha    1    7'259.73   -87.428904
BTCAlpha    1    7'259.71   -0.174233
BTCAlpha    1    7'264.84   -184.374273
BTCAlpha    2    7'264.78   673.001954
BTCBeta1    2    7'264.80   35.321462
```

I group by Exchange and sum on Total with:

```
g = df.groupby('Exchange')
series = g.apply(lambda x: x[x['Dir'] == 2]['Total'].sum())
```

I check that series is indeed a series with:

```
isinstance(series,pd.Series)
```

and it returns True

So far so good. Then I want to convert this series to Pandas dataframe with:

```
df2 = series.to_frame
```

But df2 does not become a dataframe, not sure what it becomes:

```
isinstance(df2,pd.DataFrame)
```

Returns False

```
isinstance(df2,pd.Series)
```

Returns False also.

df2 returns:

```
<bound method Series.to_frame of Exchange
BTCAlpha          1.974598e+08
BitBay            6.216426e+05
...               ...
```

I cannot sort df2, it does not appear to be a dataframe.

Comment: `df2 = series.to_frame` just assigns `df2` to the method (hence why you're seeing `<bound method Series.to_frame of Exchange`)... you need to **call** that method... `df2 = series.to_frame()`...

Comment: However, your grouping by operations look a little weird... what is it you're trying to do there? I'm sure there's a better method...

Comment: I agree with @JonClements, can you provide some more context for this? Why do you even want to convert `series` variable to a DataFrame?

Comment: Because I have some code to create a chart that is already working  and it takes a dataframe as an input. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to call the method as follows

```
df2 = series.to_frame()
```

you are missing brackets

Comment: Thanks. Beginner's mistake. Problem fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind not actually calling the method (as M_S_N) has pointed out - is there any reason you couldn't create an aggregate DF and then do what you need with that, eg:

```
agg = df.groupby(['Dir', 'Exchange'])['Total'].sum()
```

That'll then give you:

```
Dir  Exchange
1    BTCAlpha   -271.977410
2    BTCAlpha    673.001954
     BTCBeta1     35.321462
```

Then doing `agg.loc[2]` will give you series of values (for `Dir == 2`) indexed by `Exchange`:

```
Exchange
BTCAlpha    673.001954
BTCBeta1     35.321462
```

And if you want the sum across exchanges for that `Dir`, then `.sum()` again, eg:

```
agg.loc[2].sum()
# 708.323416
```